How does data concatenation with xarray work when individual datasets have different values for the same coordinate axis?
I have a case where I am trying to cast multiple Datasets into one combined Dataset. Each Dataset corresponds to an instance of an experiment. However, the instances can have different values along their main coordinate axis. To give an example data set of temperature & pressure measured in two houses with different sets of rooms:
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

houses = ["House_0", "House_1"]
ds = []

for house in houses:
    if house == "House_0":
        rooms = ["Kitchen", "Bedroom", "Lounge"]
    elif house == "House_1":
        rooms = ["Garage", "Bathroom", "Basement"]

    temperature = np.random.rand(len(rooms))
    pressure = np.random.rand(len(rooms))
    
    coords_label = "".join(["Rooms_", house])

    ds.append(xr.Dataset({
        "Temperature": ([coords_label], temperature),
        "Pressure": ([coords_label], pressure)
        },
        coords={coords_label: rooms}
        ))

hs = xr.Variable("House", houses)
data = xr.concat(ds, hs)


I would expect data.sel({"House": "House_0"}) to yield a (3,2) array corresponding to the temperature and pressure values for the rooms in ["Kitchen", "Bedroom", "Lounge"]. Instead it gives a (3,3,2) array with these values duplicated also for the coordinates in ["Garage", "Bathroom", "Basement")], which is the values for the coordinate axis I want to associate with "House_1".
>>> data.sel({"House": "House_0"})

<xarray.Dataset> Size: 352B
Dimensions:        (Rooms_House_0: 3, Rooms_House_1: 3)
Coordinates:
  * Rooms_House_0  (Rooms_House_0) <U7 84B 'Kitchen' 'Bedroom' 'Lounge'
  * Rooms_House_1  (Rooms_House_1) <U8 96B 'Garage' 'Bathroom' 'Basement'
    House          <U7 28B 'House_0'
Data variables:
    Temperature    (Rooms_House_0, Rooms_House_1) float64 72B 0.1554 ... 0.4636
    Pressure       (Rooms_House_0, Rooms_House_1) float64 72B 0.3852 ... 0.2642

Ideally, I would name both axes simply "Rooms", and give them different values for each DataSet, but in that case concat returns a DataSet with "Rooms" = ["Garage", "Bathroom", "Basement"], so I give them a unique variable name for each House.
I see two options: either I use two separate DataSets as they are, which is not ideal as I would like to be able to search by House.; or I include "Rooms" as a Variable rather than a coordinate.
Is there another way to do this? Is concat the wrong thing to use in this situation?
